# PyQGIS, custom processing algorithm: How to use selected features only?

Tags: algorithm, processing, qgis, pyqgis

I want to create a custom processing algorithm with PyQGIS, which is able to take a vector layer as input (in this case of type point) and then do something with it's features. It's working well as long as I just choose the whole layer. But it doesn't work if I'm trying to work on selected features only.

I'm using `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` to be able to work on selected features only. The option is shown and I can enable the checkbox. But when I'm executing the algorithm, I get `NoneType` as return of `parameterAsVectorLayer`.

Below you'll find a minimal working example to reproduce the problem:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProcessing,
    QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
    QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
)

name = "selectedonly"
display_name = "Selected features only example"
group = "Test"
group_id = "test"
short_help_string = "Minimal working example code for showing my problem."

class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return name

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr(display_name)

    def group(self):
        return self.tr(group)

    def groupId(self):
        return group_id

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr(short_help_string)

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                'INPUT',
                self.tr('Some point vector layer.'),
                types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            'INPUT',
            context
        )
        return {"OUTPUT": layer}
```

If I'm working on the whole layer, the output is {'OUTPUT': <QgsVectorLayer: 'Neuer Temporärlayer' (memory)>}, which is what I would expect.

If I'm working on selected features only, my output is {'OUTPUT': None}, which doesn't makes sense to me. I selected some of the features before executing of course.

I'm using QGIS-version 3.22 LTR, if it's relevant.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you trying to use the method 'parameterAsSource' in the 'processAlgorithm' method.

```
layer = self.parameterAsSource(
        parameters,
        'INPUT',
        context
    )
```